# JS fails reading upcoming array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The goal is to create navigation out of a JSON-file in the #left div-box. There should be links to the previous/next page according to the file hierarchy in the #right div-box.

My implementation is running very weirdly. When you click on a link in the navigation, only the link to the previous page shows up. By clicking on said previous link, the one to the next page is updating as well. Navigating through those 2 previous/next links works. As soon as you switch back to navigating through the navigation on the left the next page link won't update anymore. The previous one still does. 
Try it out yourself: 
http://jsfiddle.net/cxdL3/6/

From what I found out the problem is reading an element ahead in the array ([subchap+1]) doesen't *always* work. Which confuses me as it should be loaded before the functions are getting called.

Do you have an explanation for that behavior? The two links are also basically created the same way.

```
var chap; //position in the array of the currently open chapter
var subchap; //position in the array of the currently open subchapter

function update_right() {       
    var path = data.chapter[chap].subchapter;       
    //Previous Page
    if(subchap > 0) {
        $("#prev").html("<b>Previous: </b><a href='"+path[subchap-1].url+"'>"+path[subchap-1].title+"</a><br/>");
        $("#prev > a").click(back);
    } else { //subchap == 0
        $("#prev").html(""); 
    };

    //Next Page
    if(subchap+1 < path.length) {
        $("#next").html("<b>Next: </b><a href='"+path[subchap+1].url+"'>"+path[subchap+1].title+"</a><br/>");
        $("#next > a").click(next);
    } else {
        $("#next").html(""); 
    }
}

function back() {
    subchap--;
    update_right();
}

function next() {
    subchap++;
    update_right();
}

$(document).ready(function() // DOM needs to exist in order to be able to add stuff in there
{ 

//... Navigation created ...

    //------ onClick Navigation
    $('#left > ul > li > a').click(
        function()
        {
            chap = $(this).attr("data-chap");
            subchap = $(this).attr("data-subchap");
            update_right();
        }
    );  
});
```

The remaining files are pretty standard. In case they matter, they can be found here: http://fabitosh.bplaced.net/SkriptET_iFrame_v3/

Comment: Someone correctly mentioned, that `if(subchap < path.length)` should be `if(subchap+1 < path.length)`, but deleted his post soon later. Thanks for the correction, which sadly does not solve the other problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When getting `chap` and `subchap` values in your click handlers, get them as integers, not strings:

```
chap = parseInt($(this).attr("data-chap"), 10);
subchap = parseInt($(this).attr("data-subchap"), 10);
```

so that things like `chap + 1` become `1` when `chap == 0`, instead of `"01"` when `chap == "0"`

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/cxdL3/10/

Answer (score 0):

If you use `$(object).data('chap')`, jQuery will handle the type conversion for you.